# Example for flask-dynamodb that is throwing an exception for Syntax error?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-dynamodb

Looking at the example for the flask_dynamo api.  https://flask-dynamo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html  Just curious why this would give an error?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_dynamo import Dynamo



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DYNAMO_TABLES'] = [
            {
                 TableName='users',
                 KeySchema=[dict(AttributeName='username', KeyType='HASH')],
                 AttributeDefinitions=[dict(AttributeName='username', AttributeType='S')],
                 ProvisionedThroughput=dict(ReadCapacityUnits=5, WriteCapacityUnits=5)
            }, {
                 TableName='groups',
                 KeySchema=[dict(AttributeName='name', KeyType='HASH')],
                 AttributeDefinitions=[dict(AttributeName='name', AttributeType='S')],
                 ProvisionedThroughput=dict(ReadCapacityUnits=5, WriteCapacityUnits=5)
            }
        ]
```

The error is:   TableName='users',
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How is this invalid syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a typo in the docs? I'm guessing the intention is to have the items in the array as dictionaries. Try to do that:

```py
app.config['DYNAMO_TABLES'] = [
            dict(
                 TableName='users',
                 KeySchema=[dict(AttributeName='username', KeyType='HASH')],
                 AttributeDefinitions=[dict(AttributeName='username', AttributeType='S')],
                 ProvisionedThroughput=dict(ReadCapacityUnits=5, WriteCapacityUnits=5)
            ),
            dict(
                 TableName='groups',
                 KeySchema=[dict(AttributeName='name', KeyType='HASH')],
                 AttributeDefinitions=[dict(AttributeName='name', AttributeType='S')],
                 ProvisionedThroughput=dict(ReadCapacityUnits=5, WriteCapacityUnits=5)
            )
        ]
```